# Finiteness of almost maximal submonoids in positive braids

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, braid-groups

A numerical semigroup of genus $g$ is a submonoid $S=S+S$ of $\mathbb N$ missing $g$ elements (gaps) of $\mathbb N$. It is not hard to show that
there are only finitely many numerical semigroups of given genus. Finiteness is easily seen to persist for the obvious generalisation to $\mathbb N^d$ for all natural integers $d$.

I wonder if this finiteness condition persists when generalising $\mathbb N$ noncommutatively by working with braid-groups on more than two strands:
Does the monoid of all positive braids (with respect to the Dehornoy order) on $n\geq 3$ strands admit only a finite number of submonoids missing exactly $g$ positive elements?
(The braid group on two strands is the abelian group $\mathbb Z$ with positive braids
defining the monoid $\mathbb N$ giving rise to
numerical semigroups.) I ignore the answer already for the braid group $B_3$ (a central extension of
$PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$) on $3$ strands.

If I understand correctly my glimpses at a few quickly googled references, positive monoids in braid groups are finitely generated (clearly a necessary condition for finiteness). Moreover there seems to be more generally a notion of Garside monoids
(generalising monoids of positive braids in braid groups) where the above question makes perhaps sense.

Can the case of $B_3$ (or perhaps even $B_n$) be settled (either by describing an infinite number of different submonoids in positive braids all missing exactly $g$ positive elements for some value of $g$ or by giving
for example an upper bound (depending on $g$) for the number of such objects)?

Is there some convincing argument for the answer to go one way or the other?
(A negative answer for $B_n$ kills of course the question for all $m\geq n$.)